# Eclipse new plugin Project: Not choosable

Tags: eclipse-plugin

just an easy quesition but I can't find any answer in this wonderful world wide web...

I just want to create a new **Plugin Project** based on **Eclipse Helios**. Normally this feature should be shipped with this version (Version: Helios Service Release 2 Build id: 20110301-1815) but I can't choose it via "file->new->Project". Do I have sth. to install previously?

Thanks a lot for any help guys ... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install [Eclipse for RCP and RAP developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-rcp-and-rap-developers/heliossr2).

Comment: Found manual pde download plugin: [link](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.0.2-200503110845/index.php)

Answer (score 6):

It is also possible to do plugin development with any eclipse classic version. (I am working with 4.2)
For plugin development in eclipse classic version you need to go

Help-->Install New Software--> In work with select version url provided by eclipse it self. e.g. in case of 4.2 Juno it will be Juno - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno

It will render all the possible plugin provided by eclipse it self.

In that list there will a Eclipse plugin development environment in General purpose tools.

Or you can get that one by writing plug in filter text box.

Select Eclipse plugin development environment and install it.

Now you can able to do plugin development in classic version also.

Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If you already installed Eclipse you can add on the Plug-in Environment from within Eclipse

https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/273044/

> The Plugin Perspective is not installed.
>
> **To get it: Help->Install New Software**
>
> Work With: --All Available Sites--
> In the Filter Box, type "Plug-in"
> Look for something that says "General Purpose Tools" and expand it.
> Look for "Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment"
> Click Next a few times and install it, then restart.
>
> Exact verbiage may depend on your Eclipse version.

Comment: this helped me a lot with installing.