# Plug-in project option not available in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have installed eclipse Helios and want to create a plugin project. I select File --> New --> Project but there I do-not see the option for Plugin development. There are only 4 options--
General, CVS , Java and Examples.

Here are the eclipse details--
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: Helios Service Release 2
Build id: 20110218-0911

Do I need to configure anything in the eclipse settings or preferences for this?

Comment: Seems to be same problem as as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945300/eclipse-new-plugin-project-not-choosable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install the *Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers* package of eclipse, not the one for Java Developers.

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-rcp-and-rap-developers/indigosr1

**Edit:** As an alternative you can install the plugins for plugin development into your existing installation. But this might require some fiddling.

Comment: If you don't want to work with RCP & RAP version, then you can work with classic version also.In this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945300/eclipse-new-plugin-project-not-choosable it is answered how to do this for eclipse classic version.

Answer (score 1):

The reason there might be no "Plugin Project" option in your Eclipse IDE could be due to the fact that the IDE you have installed does not include the necessary components for plugin development.

to get the plugin project flow the below steps.

1. Open Eclipse and go to the Help menu, then select "Eclipse Marketplace".
2. In the Marketplace window, search for "PDE" and select the "Eclipse PDE" option from the list.
3. Click on the "Install" button next to the Eclipse PDE option, and follow the prompts to complete the installation process